# How to present modal in full screen except status bar area in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

When I open a new view controller, it goes either full screen, showing content behind the status bar, or in a rounded rectangle with the top part of the previous view visible.

I have tried all of the UIModalPresentationStyle flags, but none would show the view controller full screen except the status bar.

Is this really not implemented, and am I supposed to make a 20 px tall transparent box at the top of the page instead?

Comment: Would you not just use a safe area constraint at the top of your view?

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. It just seems weird that when I launch my app, it leaves the status bar intact, but if I open a new view controller, I cannot do the same by default.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard for your initial view controller?  By default it won't have "use full screen" enabled, so it will respect the safe area.  If you are using a fullscreen. Jew then it is up to you to layout your content relative to the safe area layout guide.

Comment: Yes, I am using a storyboard. Actually it does not make any difference whether I check or uncheck the Use Full Screen option. It is deprecated anyway.

Comment: Now I see that even on the lauch page the background I set appears in the status bar. I thought there is a default presentation style that leaves the status bar intact, so if the user chooses a light or dark theme, my background will not affect it in the status bar area.

Comment: That's just what I am used to from Android development.

Comment: You need to constrain to the top safe area layout margin not the top view margin.  It isn't safe to just assume that the status bar is 20 pixels.  It could change.  If you use safe area margins then if Apple changes things your app will still layout correctly.

Comment: It is right, constraining a subview within the main view to the bottom of <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="105318"/> will respect the status bar. However the same seems to be happening when you constrain it to the topMargin of the main view with a constant of 0.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio though. In Xcode the default storyboard is apparently a little different.

Comment: No, it was about the status bar, but the question it already answered.